# Loading UserControl to ItemsControl with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, itemscontrol

I have a UserControl which I would like to load multiple times on my MainWindow.
For this I use an `ItemsControl`:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FtpControlList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                 IsItemsHost="True" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:BackUpControl}">
      <my:BackUpControl Margin="5"
                        Width="500" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My UserControl is bound by a ViewModel. My MainWindow also has a ViewModel.
In the MainWindowViewModel I have an OberservableCollection dependency property which houlds a list of my UserControlViewModels. In the constructor of the MainWindowViewModel I add some UserControlViewModels to the List.

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
{
  FtpControlList = new ObservableCollection<BackUpControlViewModel>();
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 1"));
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 2"));
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 3"));
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FtpControlListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FtpControlList", typeof(ObservableCollection<BackUpControlViewModel>), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));
public ObservableCollection<BackUpControlViewModel> FtpControlList
{
  get { return (ObservableCollection<BackUpControlViewModel>)GetValue(FtpControlListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(FtpControlListProperty, value); }
}
```

Now for some reason it loads 3 times an empty usercontrol and NOT the ones in the FtpControlList property withe the property set to 'View 1, View 2 and View 3'. How can I make sure that the UserControls from the list are loaded and not empty ones?

Part of the UserControlViewModel:

```
    // part of the UserControl Viewmodel
    public BackUpControlViewModel()
{
}

public BackUpControlViewModel(string header)
{
  GroupBoxHeader = header;
}

    #region Dependency Properties
public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupBoxHeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GroupBoxHeader", typeof(string), typeof(BackUpControlViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata("empty"));
public string GroupBoxHeader
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(GroupBoxHeaderProperty); }
  set { SetValue(GroupBoxHeaderProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FtpUrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FtpUrl", typeof(string), typeof(BackUpControlViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata("ftpurl"));
public string FtpUrl
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(FtpUrlProperty); }
  set { SetValue(FtpUrlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FtpUserProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FtpUser", typeof(string), typeof(BackUpControlViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata("ftpUser"));
public string FtpUser
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(FtpUserProperty); }
  set { SetValue(FtpUserProperty, value); }
}
#endregion
```

It will probably be something stupid but I can't seem to find it.
The datacontext for MainWindow and the UserControl are bound to it's Viewmodel.

EDIT: BackupControl datacontext set to BackupControlViewModel (to answer Rachel's question)

```
   public partial class BackUpControl : UserControl
  {
    public BackUpControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new BackUpControlViewModel();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `BackUpControlViewModel` actually a `UserControl`? Or do you set the `DataContext` anywhere in the UserControl `my:BackUpControl`? Based on your code provided, WPF should load you three blank `my:BackUpControl` objects, with the `DataContext` behind those objects bound to the `BackUpControlViewModel`

Comment: @Rachel. I've edited my post and added the datacontext setting for the BackupUserControl. What you say is correct, it loads me 3 blank usercontrols. But why doesn't it load my 3 usercontrol viewmodels I add to FtpControlList in the MainViewModel? See     public MainWindowViewModel()
{
  FtpControlList = new ObservableCollection<BackUpControlViewModel>();
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 1"));
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 2"));
  FtpControlList.Add(new BackUpControlViewModel("View 3"));
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` by setting it in the constructor of your `UserControl` after calling `InitializeComponent();`

By default, the `ItemsControl` will create an `ItemTemplate` for each item in the collection, and set it's `DataContext` to the item from the `ItemsSource`. The end result will be three new `my:BackUpControl` objects, with the `DataContext` behind those objects bound to the `BackUpControlViewModel` from `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`

Remove the line `this.DataContext = new BackUpControlViewModel();` from your UserControl's constructor, and it should work like you expect

Comment: Thx, that did it. I knew it was something with the binding but couldn't see what.. It gets me confused sometimes :) You're great!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that your viewmodel has dependency properties. Normally you would just make your viewmodel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the properties would be regular (not dependency properties). Unless you have a specific requirement for them to be DPs I'd switch them over.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I changed the GroupBoxHeader proprty to a NotifyChanged property but the result is the same..

Comment: are there any binding errors in your output? Something along the lines of 'Binding error: Property blah doesn't exist...'

Comment: Yeah indeed, following error for all my properties: System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=GroupBoxHeader; DataItem=null; target element is 'GroupBox' (Name='groupBox1'); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object') But how to fix this? I must do something wrong with the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:BackUpControl}">
```

To:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:BackUpControlViewModel}">
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still loads 3 empty usercontrol viewmodels and not the ones I add to the FtpControlList on the MainWindowViewModel..

Comment: Does it at least load BackUpControl instances? You need to identify if the problem is the template not being applied or if some bindings in your BackUpControls are not being evaluated correctly. In the later we need to check your BackUpControl xaml to check how it is supposed to look.